# SQL Command not returning specific record

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

so i have a program in `C#` that accesses a old `Firebird 1.5` database from a third party program. One of the methods i have will fetch data for either a quote or a project by id: (sorry about some Portuguese words in there)

```
public static List<object> GetFollowUpData(int id, TipoFollowUp tipo)
    {
        var res = new List<object>();
        string q = tipo == TipoFollowUp.Orcamento
            ? "SELECT ('Q-' || c.CLIENT_CODE || q.CQUO_FNUMB) as Codigo, q.CQUO_NAME as Nome, q.CQUO_SENT as Data, q.CQUO_TOTAL as Total, c.CLIENT_NAME as Empresa, m.CCON_NAME as Contacto, ((CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE1 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE1 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE2 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE2 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE3 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE3 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE4 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE4 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE1 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE1 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE2 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE2 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE3 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE3 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE4 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE4 end)) as Telefones FROM CMULTIQUOTES q, CLIENTS c, CCONTACTS m WHERE q.ID = @id AND c.CLIENT_ID = q.CLIENT_ID AND q.CLIENT_PM = m.CCON_ID"
            : "SELECT q.PROJ_CODE as Codigo, q.PROJ_NAME as Nome, q.PROJ_COMPLETED as Data, (select sum(j.CJOB_TOTAL) from CJOBS j where j.PROJ_ID = @id) as Total, c.CLIENT_NAME as Empresa, m.CCON_NAME as Contacto, ((CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE1 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE1 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE2 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE2 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE3 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE3 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN m.CCON_PHONE4 IS null then '' else m.CCON_PHONE4 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE1 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE1 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE2 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE2 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE3 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE3 end) || '/' || (CASE WHEN c.CLIENT_PHONE4 IS null then '' else c.CLIENT_PHONE4 end)) as Telefones FROM PROJECTS q, CLIENTS c, CCONTACTS m WHERE q.PROJ_ID = @id AND c.CLIENT_ID = q.CLIENT_ID AND q.CLIENT_PM = m.CCON_ID";
        using (var cmd = new FbCommand(q) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
        using (cmd.Connection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
            using (FbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    res.Add(id); // ID
                    res.Add(reader[0]); // Código
                    res.Add(reader[1]); // Nome
                    res.Add(reader[2]); // Data
                    res.Add(reader[3]); // Total
                    res.Add(reader[4]); // Empresa
                    res.Add(reader[5]); // Contacto
                    res.Add(reader[6]); // Telefones
                    res.Add(tipo); // Tipo
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

This works most of the time - but for a specific project it's not returning any data (project id 8771)

I've copy pasted the second query into FlameRobin, connected it to the database and replaced @id in the query with 8771 and flameRobin returns the data i want.

So if FlameRobin can get the data using my query, why doesn't my program get it too?
in My method above, `Reader.Read()` imediatly returns false and i get no data from the database for that project. Other projects and quotes so far had no issues returning the data as far as i've detected

Anyone ahs any ideas?

Comment: What is the data of the record that cannot be read? Are there any strange characters (embedded newlines, nulls or other strange characters), any column that is null (but isn't in any other record)?.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck As per FlameRobin non of the returned data is null or empty for that matter. I can't exactly post the data itself as it contains personal data from clients but no newlines or nulls are presente - not sure what you mean with strange characters there

Comment: I see that you have 2 different select statements. Have you tried both in FlameRobin?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck One is quotes and one is for projects - i've checked and it is using the bottom one for this particular one so the other one doesn't come into play - and so far as worked unlike the second which fails in this particular case

Comment: I would take a record that returns correctly compared to the results that do not.  See if you can find any difference, or as Klas mentioned, a weird character in the non returned result compared to the other one.   Go column by column and see if you can find a hidden culprit.

Comment: @user3241191 FlameRobin doesn't show anything off and my program won't return any data that i can compare - which complicates things here. I can tell though that at one time it did return the data as i've found mention to it on my programs own database. Need to research this further

Comment: I was referring to the results in FlameRobin with a query that returns good in your program and one that does not.  Maybe FlameRobin could be hiding something that could be throwing things off in your program with that particular result set?  These are just wild guesses since we can't see the data.

Comment: Ok - so i added a protection code so that when it returns nothing will not break things. i simply make it an empty result set - and now it suddenly is getting the data... odd

Comment: Ok - figured out what was wrong. My stupidity. There are two copies of that third party database - one for development/tests and one for production. Was using one in the program (in VS) and looking at another in FlameRobin - Lack of sync was causing this. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone
Just spent half a morning around this to finally figure out i was using my development/test database copy in the program (under VS) and connecting to the production copy in FlameRobin.

Lack of sync between the tw databases was causing this

The project in question existed in the production copy - thus FlameRobin was showing it - but not in the development/test copy used by the program

Sorry